# Scroll Group tableView when keyboard appears

Tags: iphone, objective-c, ios, uitableview, uitextview

I'm trying to create a view, where user enter his info (name, email, bio...).

To do this I'm using a group table view with 5 section (0..4), each has one cell that has a `UITextField` inside (except the cell in section 4 that has a `UITextView` inside).

When user tap on one of those textFields/textView the keyboard appears, and the cell (with the selected textField/textView) scroll to the position just above the keyboard.

My problem is with the textView at section 4, when keyboard appears it somehow automatically scroll the cell to be visible, but not exactly in the right position (half of the text view is hidden behind the keyboard).
When I try to do the scroll myself (after keyboard finish animating) I get an ugly bounce of the textView.

It seams that the cause for the ugly bounce is that the textView automatic scrolls when the keyboard appear + my scrolling. This behavior (of automatic scrolling) happens only for the textView, for example if I use a textField instead of the textView in section 4, it doesn't automatically scroll.

So the question is: how can I smoothly scroll the textView to the right position?

This is my code:

```
#pragma mark - UITableViewDataSource

- (NSInteger)numberOfSectionsInTableView:(UITableView *)tableView {
    return 5;
}

- (NSInteger)tableView:(UITableView *)tableView numberOfRowsInSection:(NSInteger)section {
    return 1;
}

- (UITableViewCell *)tableView:(UITableView *)tableView cellForRowAtIndexPath:(NSIndexPath *)indexPath {
    UITableViewCell *cell = [[UITableViewCell alloc] initWithStyle:UITableViewCellStyleDefault reuseIdentifier:nil];

    switch (indexPath.section) {
        case 0:
            [cell.contentView addSubview:self.textField1];
            break;
        case 1:
            [cell.contentView addSubview:self.textField2];
            break;
        case 2:
            [cell.contentView addSubview:self.textField3];
            break;
        case 3:
            [cell.contentView addSubview:self.textField4];
            break;
        case 4:
            // this is the text view
            [cell.contentView addSubview:self.textView];
            break;
        default:
            break;
    }

    cell.selectionStyle = UITableViewCellSelectionStyleNone;

    return cell;
}



#pragma mark - UITextFieldDelegate

- (BOOL)textFieldShouldBeginEditing:(UITextField *)textField {
    self.activeResponder = textField;
    return YES;
}

#pragma mark - UITextViewDelegate

- (BOOL)textViewShouldBeginEditing:(UITextView *)textView {
    self.activeResponder = textView;
    return YES;
}

- (void)keyboardWillShow:(NSNotification*)notification {
    NSLog(@"keyboard show");
    CGFloat animationDuration = [[[notification userInfo] objectForKey:UIKeyboardAnimationDurationUserInfoKey] doubleValue];
    CGRect keyboardFrame = [[[notification userInfo] objectForKey:UIKeyboardFrameEndUserInfoKey] CGRectValue];

    CGRect tableViewFrame = self.tableView.frame;
    tableViewFrame.size.height -= keyboardFrame.size.height;

    [UIView animateWithDuration:animationDuration delay:0.0 options:UIViewAnimationOptionBeginFromCurrentState animations:^{
        self.tableView.frame = tableViewFrame;
    } completion:^(BOOL finished) {
        [self scrollToActiveResponder];
    }];
}

- (void)keyboardWillHide:(NSNotification*)notification {
    NSLog(@"keyboard hide");
    CGFloat animationDuration = [[[notification userInfo] objectForKey:UIKeyboardAnimationDurationUserInfoKey] doubleValue];
    CGRect keyboardFrame = [[[notification userInfo] objectForKey:UIKeyboardFrameEndUserInfoKey] CGRectValue];

    CGRect tableViewFrame = self.tableView.frame;
    tableViewFrame.size.height += keyboardFrame.size.height;

    [UIView animateWithDuration:animationDuration delay:0.0 options:UIViewAnimationOptionBeginFromCurrentState animations:^{
        self.tableView.frame = tableViewFrame;
    } completion:^(BOOL finished) {
    }];
}     

- (NSIndexPath *)indexPathForActiveResponder {
        NSIndexPath *indexPath = nil;
        if (self.activeResponder == self.textField1) {
            indexPath = [NSIndexPath indexPathForRow:0 inSection:0];
        }
        else if (self.activeResponder == self.textField2) {
            indexPath = [NSIndexPath indexPathForRow:0 inSection:1];
        }
        else if (self.activeResponder == self.textField3) {
            indexPath = [NSIndexPath indexPathForRow:0 inSection:2];
        }
        else if (self.activeResponder == self.textField4) {
            indexPath = [NSIndexPath indexPathForRow:0 inSection:3];
        }
        else if (self.activeResponder == self.textView) {
            indexPath = [NSIndexPath indexPathForRow:0 inSection:4];
        }
        return indexPath;
    } 

- (void)scrollToActiveResponder {
    NSIndexPath *activeResponderIndexPath = [self indexPathForActiveResponder];
    if (activeResponderIndexPath) {
        [self.tableView scrollToRowAtIndexPath:activeResponderIndexPath atScrollPosition:UITableViewScrollPositionNone animated:YES];
    }
}
```

Answer (score 0):

I would try something like this:

.h

```
@interface YourViewController : UIViewController <UITextViewDelegate>
```

.m

```
//Set delegate to your textView
textView.delegate = self

#pragma mark - TextView Delegate
//TextView Became First Responder
- (void)textViewDidBeginEditing:(UITextView *)textView{

    NSIndexPath *indexPath = [NSIndexPath indexPathForRow:0 inSection:4];

    // Other way to get the IndexPath
    //NSIndexPath *indexPath = [self.tableView indexPathForCell:(UITableViewCell *)[[textView superview] superview]];

    CGRect frame = [self.tableView rectForRowAtIndexPath:indexPath];

    //It only works for Portrait iPhone
    CGFloat keyboardHeight = 216.0f;

    CGPoint offset = CGPointMake(0, self.view.frame.size.height - keyboardHeight - frame.size.height - frame.origin.y);
    [self.tableView setContentOffset:offset animated:YES];

}
```

I didn't test it, but it's how I would try to approach this problem. You can find more information about how calculate keyboard size here: (http://www.idev101.com/code/User_Interface/keyboard.html)